# /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lGL (Ubuntu 14.04)

Tags: c++, linux, qt, ubuntu, gcc

I'm trying to build a project created in QT Creator and unfortunately every time I try to compile I get an error. Here is my compiler output:

```
23:02:20: Running steps for project WallpaperAppQt...
23:02:20: Configuration unchanged, skipping qmake step.
23:02:20: Starting: "/usr/bin/make" 
g++ -m64 -o WallpaperAppQt main.o mainwindow.o moc_mainwindow.o   -L/usr/X11R6/lib64 -lQt5Widgets -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -lQt5Gui -lQt5Core -lGL -lpthread 
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lGL
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [WallpaperAppQt] Error 1
23:02:20: The process "/usr/bin/make" exited with code 2.
Error while building/deploying project WallpaperAppQt (kit: Desktop)
When executing step 'Make'
23:02:20: Elapsed time: 00:00.
```

Answer (score 15):

You need a package that provides the `libGL.so` (no version suffix) symlink.  In Ubuntu, it's in the `libgl1-mesa-dev` package.  So just do:

```
sudo apt install libgl1-mesa-dev
```

Comment: Better :  `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install libgl1-mesa-dev`

Comment: libgl1-mesa-dev is already installed on my system, and I still get the problem.

Comment: Run `dpkg -L libgl1-mesa-dev`.  Does it list the file `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so` (or `/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libGL.so` if you're on a 32-bit system)?  Does that file actually exist?

Comment: It lists both of them:

/usr
/usr/share
/usr/share/bug
/usr/share/bug/libgl1-mesa-dev
/usr/share/bug/libgl1-mesa-dev/script
/usr/share/bug/libgl1-mesa-dev/control
/usr/share/doc
/usr/share/doc/libgl1-mesa-dev
/usr/share/doc/libgl1-mesa-dev/copyright
/usr/share/doc/libgl1-mesa-dev/changelog.Debian.gz
/usr/lib
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig/gl.pc
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglapi.so

Comment: Found the fix here (last two commands) http://techtidings.blogspot.com/2012/01/problem-with-libglso-on-64-bit-ubuntu.html

Answer (score 9):

I was able to fix my problem by following the instructions in this link:

http://techtidings.blogspot.com/2012/01/problem-with-libglso-on-64-bit-ubuntu.html

(the final two commands)

```
sudo rm /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so 
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/libGL.so.1 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so
```

Comment: this fixed my problem ```sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1.7.0 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so```

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem. Then I used the following command in the terminal:

```
sudo apt install mesa-common-dev libglu1-mesa-dev"
```

and the application run perfectly.

Answer (score -1):

It's obvious that `ld` doesn't find `lib GL` in default library path which should be include `/lib* /usr/lib*`.  You should install library `GL` or tell `g++` where lib `GL` was installed with cmd args -L if that was installed already.